# Azure Purview Power BI scan not showing Schema for Dataset

Tags: powerbi, azure-purview

After scanning Power BI in Azure Purview, we are able to see the proper Lineage and other Properties related to the Report. But we could not find the Schema for the dataset. The schema tab is empty.

Here we use the Source for reporting as Delta tables. We expect to see the fields/columns used from the Delta tables for the Reports.

Comment: Have you also set up delta_process and other metadata items needed for lineage for Purview to read? Also Azure Purview is still in Preview and my not support what you want.

Comment: I haven't done any explicit setup for lineage, after the scan Purview by itself formed a linear lineage between Dataset and Report. But this automatic lineage creation happens only with PowerBI scan. If we scan the delta tables files from blob storage, we need to explicitly create Process to form lineage.